# WSL make multiple copies of a file

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to make multiple copies of a file. I found a readily available solution and I tried. Surprisingly it did not work.

Code:

```
for i in {1,2,3,4}; do cp MainFile.asy 'CopyFile_$i.asy'; done
```

Present output:
Folder location

```
MainFile.asy
CopyFile_$i.asy
```

I am surprised where I went wrong?
More info:
Attempt1:
[image]

Attempt2: from below accepted answer and it worked
[image]

Attemp3: from below answer and it did not work
[image]

Comment: `>> ` is that even a shell

Comment: @roaima I updated my question and one of the solutions worked, not the others. Also, I am looking at how to generate a list of numbers something like this `(1..16)` and I don't want to type all the numbers.

Comment: @Michael Homer I updated my question.

Comment: Read more carefully and stop using `%`.

Comment: @TomYan Sure! it came from my Python habit. I corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the single quotes which prevent $i from being expanded. Change it to this:

```bsh
for i in {1,2,3,4}; do cp MainFile.asy "CopyFile_$i.asy"; done
```

For a more generic version that works in more shells maybe try:

```bsh
for i in 1 2 3 4; do cp MainFile.asy "CopyFile_$i.asy"; done
```

Or this without manually entering each value in the range:

```bsh
for i in $(seq 1 4); do cp MainFile.asy "CopyFile_$i.asy"; done
```

Comment: It did not work. It just produced one file with name "CopyFile_.asy"

Comment: @Mainland Which shell are you using?

Comment: WSL with Penguin ICON

Comment: @Mainland I tried WSL Ubuntu, Debian, and Kali and didn't see any problems. I tested bash, zsh, ksh, dash, and busybox. Maybe a copy/paste problem?

Comment: Just to make sure, I tried the simple code `>> cat MainFile.asy CopyFile_1.asy` and it worked perfectly and `CopyFile_1.asy` is created. I am surprised and don't know what to do. Also, I tried `$(seq 1 4)` and it produced no output.

Comment: The code @CR, gave should definitely work. I can only think you're not doing exactly what was suggested. You can also try `for (( i=1 ; i<=4 ; i++)) ; do cp MainFiie.asy "CopyFile_$i.asy" ; done`

Comment: @frabjous Did not work. I don't know why. I made sure that code is correct.

Comment: @Mainland Are you getting any output in the shape "i: command not found" when you run these? Can you edit your question with the results of each of these attempts?

Comment: @Mainland are you in the python interpreter? Exit that so you are at the shell prompt

Comment: @Mainland are you getting any errors or other messages reported? If so please tell us what they are

Comment: I updated my question and one of the solutions worked, not the others. Also, I am looking at how to generate a list of numbers something like this `(1..16)` and I don't want to type all the numbers.

Comment: @Mainland wrong brackets; use `{1..16}` instead

Comment: @roaima you are correct. It worked now.  Thanks a ton.